# Configuring Terraform GKE Plugin IP Ranges for pods and services

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to use the [Terraform Module for GKE](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-google-modules/kubernetes-engine/google/0.4.0) but I'm not sure how to configure the properties `ip_range_pods` and `ip_range_services`.

Specifically, I'm not sure how they derived these values:

```
  ip_range_pods              = "us-central1-01-gke-01-pods"
  ip_range_services          = "us-central1-01-gke-01-services"
```

Comment: You might find more luck with the google provider rather than using this extra module. See https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/container_cluster.html, it's better documented too. However it does require a bit more technical knowledge.

Comment: Yeah, agreed. I think using the google provider and being able to map things to the CLI options is quite helpful.

Comment: @PaulAnnetts I found the google provider better documented and more flexible too. However, it does not support adding labels to the node pool instances per node pool - which is something I was looking for specifically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ip_range_pods` and `ip_range_services` map to the [`ip_allocation_policy`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/container_cluster.html#ip_allocation_policy) [`cluster_secondary_range_name`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/container_cluster.html#cluster_secondary_range_name) and [`services_secondary_range_name`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/container_cluster.html#services_secondary_range_name) attributes of the `google_container_cluster` resource as can be seen in [the module source](https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-google-kubernetes-engine/blob/3f7527e583ffa07e6a06250844e07c38556a4488/cluster_zonal.tf#L58-L61):

```
resource "google_container_cluster" "zonal_primary" {
  # ...

  ip_allocation_policy {
    cluster_secondary_range_name  = "${var.ip_range_pods}"
    services_secondary_range_name = "${var.ip_range_services}"
  }
}
```

These need to be existing ranges in a subnetwork such as created by the [`google_compute_subnetwork` resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/compute_subnetwork.html):

```
resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "network-with-private-secondary-ip-ranges" {
  name          = "test-subnetwork"
  ip_cidr_range = "10.2.0.0/16"
  region        = "us-central1"
  network       = "${google_compute_network.custom-test.self_link}"
  secondary_ip_range {
    range_name    = "tf-test-secondary-range-update1"
    ip_cidr_range = "192.168.10.0/24"
  }
}

resource "google_compute_network" "custom-test" {
  name                    = "test-network"
  auto_create_subnetworks = false
}
```

Comment: Thanks heaps for the detailed explanation and links! =D

Comment: How do you use the default one provided? Without the module you can completely omit this part and the default take care of the rest?

* later edit * it seems providing the values ip_range_pods  and ip_range_services as empty strings (not mentioned anywhere)

Comment: Hello, does ip_range_pods can be edited afterwards ?